# Will mqttv3 work in Java 1.4

Tags: java, mqtt, paho

Does any one know if its possible to use the org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3 client version 1.0.2 in a java application that must be coded with Java 1.4 ?

I could not see where the minimum java requirement. Please let me know if its published and where if i missed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the parent `pom.xml` found in the sources you can download from the project's [site](https://eclipse.org/paho/clients/java/) using

```
git clone http://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/paho/org.eclipse.paho.mqtt.java.git


<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.paho</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0.2</version>

    <properties>
        <!-- source & target java version for MQTT Client -->
        <mqttclient.java.version>1.4</mqttclient.java.version>
        <!-- source & target java version for others modules -->
        <java.version>1.6</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
```

and the compiler configuration in the `pom.xml` for the client `org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3`

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
    <artifactId>tycho-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.20.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>${mqttclient.java.version}</source>
        <target>${mqttclient.java.version}</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

You can see that the version `1.0.2` is set up to compile against java `1.4` (the value of the property `mqttclient.java.version`).

So using it for java application targeted for version `1.4` should be possible.